# jquery field tooltip

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, tooltip

I want to display the tooltip beside the form field input text box on focus the input textbox element.I had used the jquery plugin from the [jquery plugin](http://jquery.bassistance.de/tooltip/demo/).

Please provide if any links are there for jquery form fields tooltip.

Thanks

Comment: What exactly is your issue? was the plugin you've linked to not working correctly? Please clarify what your looking for or what the issue is.

Comment: The plugin i specified is working only for mouse over the text box .But i want to display the tooltip on focus the textbox

Answer (score 0):

```
var options = {
     linktext: 'Reset',
     wrap_in_div : false,
     tooltip : 'Reset textarea|textfield to initial value.'
}
$("input[name='default']").textreset(options);
$("textarea").textareareset({ linktext : "<img src='images/left38.gif'></img>"});
```